# Modify point style when it has drawn tick in ChartJs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am migrating from Highcharts to ChartJs (v2.8), and in Highcharts, I can get the drawn ticks, and then modify the point style relational with this tick, as shown below:

[image: Points modified]

but in ChartJs I don't see any way of doing that, I don't be able to get the drawn ticks and I don't see the way of modifying the style of only some points either. It's not possible?

Actual config:

```
var options = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
    datasets: [
        {
          data: [611, 605, 594, 581, 573, 578, 585, 587, 588, 595, 601, 605, 608, 610, 612, 611, 612, 613, 616, 618, 621, 623, 625, 627, 628, 631, 636, 638, 643, 650],
        fill: false,
        borderWidth: 1,
        pointRadius: 3,
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointBackgroundColor: "#adadad",
        pointHoverRadius: 6,
        pointHoverBorderColor: "#adadad",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: `${"#adadad"}30`,
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
        },  
        ]
  },
  options: {
     responsive: true,
        tooltips: {
          mode: 'interpolate',
          intersect: false,
        },
     scales: {
            xAxes: [{
        
          gridLines: {
            display: false,
          },
          distribution: 'series',
          time: {
            displayFormats: {
              month: '%e. %b',
            },
          },
          ticks: {
            maxRotation: 0,
            autoSkip: true,
            autoSkipPadding: 10,
          },
        }],
        yAxes: [{
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
          },
          ticks: {
            padding: 15,
          },
        }],
     },
    colors: [{
      borderColor: "#adadad",
    }],
    showLegend: false,
  }
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/z39Lfmrw/43/)

Comment: can you post your chartjs data, options

Comment: added an example in jsfiddle

Comment: I think this thread will help you styling points, by creating an array of pointstyle, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52474546/point-style-property-with-inverted-image-in-line-chart-js.